# Rebinding Ctrl-Tab

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I wanted to rebind default Ctrl-Tab/Ctrl-Shift-Tab behavior (Next/Previous) to something else: (Super-H/Super-L), but I can't find the best way to do that. Looked all over in dconf editor, it's not there. Can someone help?

Manjaro on GNOME

Comment: You should not edit the gnome settings but the xorg settings. I think this question can help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices

Comment: @switch87 No, keyboard shortcuts are Gnome settings, Xorg has nothing to do with them.

Comment: ctrl-tab is keycode 94, by remapping this keycode you can give it a alternate function. of ctrl-Shift-tab, Super-H and Super-L I do not know it, you can find out with xev. After that you can let linux think they are Ctrl-tab/ctrl-shift-tab with xmodmap

Comment: @gillis normally thats true, but if you are not offered the option to change it the first next place to look for an solution is xorg.